# How to display only date "dd/MM/yyy" in primefaces calendar incide of <p:inplace/>

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, calendar

I am trying to display only date, month and year in this code, but when I put the initial date and I click the save button in the inplace this display the date so: "Thu Aug 21 00:00:00 BOT 2014"
I only want to display so: "21/08/2014" or "21/Aug/2014"

this is the code:

```
<p:outputLabel value="#{msg['startDate']}" for="inputInitialDate"/>
<p:inplace id="inputInitialDate" editor="true" emptyLabel="#{msg['period.addInitialDate']}" 
                               disabled="#{periodManager.currentPeriod.state == 'DUE'}">
    <p:ajax event="save" listener="#{periodManager.addDateToPeriod}" update="formContainer"/>
    <p:calendar value="#{periodManager.currentPeriod.initialDate}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"
                                    widgetVar="calendarInputWidget"/>
</p:inplace>
<p:message for="inputInitialDate"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

Add the `<f:convertDateTime>` to the calendar, repeating the `pattern`. The `<p:calendar>`'s own `pattern` attribute is indeed most commonly misunderstood. It only applies on the pattern which should be shown in the calendar selection popup, not on the pattern of the output.

```
<p:calendar ... pattern="dd/MM/yyyy">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
</p:calendar>
```

Or, a bit more DRY.

```
<p:calendar ... pattern="dd/MM/yyyy">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="#{component.pattern}" />
</p:calendar>
```

Comment: thanks, now it works.
For display the month literal how i should use the pattern?

Comment: The patterns are based on `SimpleDateFormat` rules which are very clearly outlined in its [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). Use `MMM` for 3-character month abbreviation and `MMMM` for the full month name. For new questions not related to the current question, please press `[Ask Question]` button in right top.